# Reversing every second "row" in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that is obtained by flattening a matrix

```
list=Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 2, 6, 2}], 1]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     6}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 6}}

And I am looking for at way to reverse all "rows" with even numbers (the first element).

So that my list will look like this

```
{{1,2}, {1,4}, {1,6}, {2,6}, {2,4}, {2,2}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {3,6}, {4,6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}
```

Note that the first element stays the same, but the last element (for list with even first element) for the whole "row" has reversed.

Maybe there is an easy solutions to this, but I have not been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, 
        {3, 6}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 6}};
Join @@ MapAt[Reverse, #, Position[#, {{x_?EvenQ, _}, ___}]] &@ GatherBy[list, First]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

It will be simpler if you store your list as

```
list2 = {{2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}}
```

where positions is the number of "row"

```
MapAt[Reverse, list2, 2 ;; ;; 2]
```

> {{2, 4, 6}, {6, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 6}, {6, 4, 2}}

Comment: e.g. with Partition[list[[All, 2]], 3] ...

Comment: Thanks. It works just fine :) The reason why the list is stored that way, is because i extracted it from a image (to one's and zeros), and used Position to extract coordinates for every one's. Thank you very much for the help. Now it's possible to make my robot draw both ways, and then minimizing the airtraveling time

Answer (score 3):

One other solution (less tricky IMO):

```
list = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 2, 6, 2}], 1];
splittedlist = SplitBy[list, EvenQ]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 2}, {3,4}, {3, 6}}, {{4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 6}}}

```
Flatten[Join[splittedlist[[#1]],Reverse@splittedlist[[#2]]] & @@@
  Partition[Range@Length@splittedlist, 2],1]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
a= {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 2}, 
   {4, 4}, {4, 6}}
```

A minor variation of ybeltukov's approach:

```
Flatten[If[EvenQ[#[[1, 1]]], Reverse[#], #] & /@ GatherBy[a, First],1]
```

Or this:

```
Join@@(GatherBy[a, First] /. {{x_?EvenQ, _}, z___} :> Append[Reverse[{z}], x])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Quiet[Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1, #2} &, GatherBy[list, First], {1}] /. {a_List, b_List} /; 
      EvenQ[b /. List -> Sequence] -> {a // Reverse, b} //. {a_List,b_List} -> a, 1]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
fun[u_?(EvenQ[#[[1, 1]]] &)] := Reverse@u;
fun[u_] := u;
g[u_] := Flatten[fun /@ GatherBy[u, First@# &], 1];
```

or

```
fun[u_?(EvenQ[#[[1, 1]]] &)] := Reverse@u;
fun[u_] := u;
h[u_] := Join@@(fun /@ GatherBy[u, First@# &]);
```

Applying to test list:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 
   4}, {3, 6}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 6}}
g[list]
```

yields:

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3,
>   6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

### SortBy

You can use `SortBy` with nested criteria making the second level sorting increasing or decreasing depending on whether the first element is odd:

> - SortBy[*list*, {$f_1$, $f_2$, ...}] *breaks ties by successively using the values obtained from the $f_i$.*

So, we just need `SortBy`:

```
SortBy[list, {First, If[EvenQ[First@#], -#, #] &}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

### Partition

You can use the (undocumented) 6th argument of `Partition` to process the groups differently based on the parity of the first elements:

```
Partition[list, 3, 3, None, {}, 
 If[OddQ @ #[[1]], Sequence @@ {##}, Sequence @@ Reverse@{##}] &]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>     6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
list={{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 
  6}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 6}};

SequenceReplace[list, 
 k : {{a_, _} ..} /; EvenQ[a] :> Sequence @@ Reverse[k]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3,
> 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {4, 2}}